# Adding a label to my css flexbox (using spectre framework) causes overlap

Tags: html, css, flexbox, spectre.css

I'm trying to create a "hat" with two `textarea` columns using the [spectre.css](https://picturepan2.github.io/spectre/index.html) framework. The intent is to have them resize depending on the size of the screen, with anything lower than 600px making the columns stacked on top of each other. I can do this just fine with the framework as long as the `textarea` doesn't have an associated `label`. However, with a `label`, it breaks - the `textarea` overlaps the current column space at the bottom. As far as I can tell, the `label` is not being factored in when calculating the size of the column and I don't know why. How do I fix this?

```css
*, ::before, ::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding-left: .4rem;
  padding-right: .4rem;
  width: 100%;
}

.columns {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-left: -.4rem;
  margin-right: -.4rem;
}

.column {
  -ms-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: .25rem;
}

.col-12,
.col-11,
.col-10,
.col-9,
.col-6 {
   -ms-flex: none;
    flex: none;
}

.col-12 {
  width: 100%;
}

.col-10 {
  width: 83.33333333%;
}

.col-9 {
  width: 75%;
}

.col-6 {
  width: 50%;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  #hattop {
    height: 35vh;
  }
  
  .column.col-sm-12,
  .column.col-sm-11 {
   -ms-flex: none;
    flex: none;
  }
  
 .col-sm-12 {
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .col-sm-11 {
    width: 91.66666667%;
  }
}

.col-mx-auto {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.col-ml-auto {
  margin-left: auto;
}

.col-mr-auto {
  margin-right: auto;
}

.form-label {
  color: #fff;
}

.form-input {
  appearance: none;
  background: #fff;
  border: .05rem solid #5755d9;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: #3b4351;
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: .25rem .4rem;
  position: relative;
  transition: background .2s, border .2s, box-shadow .2s, color .2s;
  width: 100%;
  word-wrap: anywhere;
}

textarea {
  overflow: auto;
  resize: none;
}

textarea.form-input {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#hattop {
  background-color: rgb(31, 26, 44);
  padding: 1rem .5rem;
  height: 50vh;
  border-top-left-radius: 20px;
  border-top-right-radius: 20px;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  #hattop {
    height: 35vh;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="columns col-sm-11 col-10 col-mx-auto">
        <div id="hattop" class="columns col-9 col-mx-auto">
            <div class="column col-sm-12 col-6 col-ml-auto">
                <label for="nams" class="form-label">Enter names separated by line</label>
                <textarea class="form-input" id="names" placeholder="Names"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="column col-sm-12 col-6 col-mr-auto">
                <label for="tasks" class="form-label">Enter tasks separated by line</label>
                <textarea class="form-input" id="tasks" placeholder="Tasks"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. The `#hattop` `height` attribute along with the `textarea` `height` attribute being 100% meant the `textarea` was going to always be the full height of the `hattop`, not factoring in the `label`.

I took out the `#hattop` `height` attribute. Then I changed the `textarea` `height` attribute to `50vh` for when the screen is bigger than 600px, and `20vh` for when the screen is smaller than that. It's basically the same size as the previous version but actually responsive now!

```css
*, ::before, ::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding-left: .4rem;
  padding-right: .4rem;
  width: 100%;
}

.columns {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-left: -.4rem;
  margin-right: -.4rem;
}

.column {
  -ms-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: .25rem;
}

.col-12,
.col-11,
.col-10,
.col-9,
.col-6 {
   -ms-flex: none;
    flex: none;
}

.col-12 {
  width: 100%;
}

.col-10 {
  width: 83.33333333%;
}

.col-9 {
  width: 75%;
}

.col-6 {
  width: 50%;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {

  .column.col-sm-12,
  .column.col-sm-11 {
   -ms-flex: none;
    flex: none;
  }
  
 .col-sm-12 {
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .col-sm-11 {
    width: 91.66666667%;
  }
}

.col-mx-auto {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.col-ml-auto {
  margin-left: auto;
}

.col-mr-auto {
  margin-right: auto;
}

.form-label {
  color: #fff;
}

.form-input {
  appearance: none;
  background: #fff;
  border: .05rem solid #5755d9;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: #3b4351;
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: .25rem .4rem;
  position: relative;
  transition: background .2s, border .2s, box-shadow .2s, color .2s;
  width: 100%;
  word-wrap: anywhere;
}

textarea {
  overflow: auto;
  resize: none;
}

textarea.form-input {
  height: 40vh;
  width: 100%;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
    textarea.form-input {
    height: 20vh;
  }
}


#hattop {
  background-color: rgb(31, 26, 44);
  padding: 1rem .5rem;
  border-top-left-radius: 20px;
  border-top-right-radius: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="columns col-sm-11 col-10 col-mx-auto">
        <div id="hattop" class="columns col-9 col-mx-auto">
            <div class="column col-sm-12 col-6 col-ml-auto">
                <label for="nams" class="form-label">Enter names separated by line</label>
                <textarea class="form-input" id="names" placeholder="Names"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="column col-sm-12 col-6 col-mr-auto">
                <label for="tasks" class="form-label">Enter tasks separated by line</label>
                <textarea class="form-input" id="tasks" placeholder="Tasks"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```